# Can I pass a subclass instance to a method which accepts superclass instance

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism, downcast, upcasting

I have a setup similar to this. When I try to call ***execRequest*** method using java Reflections and in  ***parameterArray*** pass the subclass instance which is ***DelRequest*** I am getting an NoSuchMethodFound Exception

```
DelRequest delReq=new DelRequest();
delReq.setMsg("something");
Request req=(Request) delReq;
```

I have few service methods and between and then eventually I call the following lines of code. Note this time I am passing  ***req*** the Superclass Instance as it is defined is methods signature ***public String execRequest(Request request)***

```
lClass.getMethod( "execRequest", parameterArray)
```

This is my basic setup kindly point where am i wrong and can it be done or not

```
class DelRequest extends Request {
private String msg;


 /* getters and setters */
}

class Request {
}



class ExecuteRequest{
public String execRequest(Request request){
/* request do something*/
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But that's not what your question is, I think.

Comment: Does `execRequest` need to be static? Static functions and inheritance are not a good mix!

Comment: sorry It is not static I will edited it

Answer (score 0):

The Reflection API requires that you use the declared types of the parameter. So even though you can invoke `execRequest` with a `DelRequest`, you'll need to use `Request.class` as an argument to [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-).

> **The `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that
>   identify the method's formal parameter types**, in declared order. If
>   `parameterTypes` is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array.

Comment: I was trying the same thing may be I am doing someting wrong. I tried to Typecast ***DelRequest**** to ***Request*** and the pass the Request instance  but this doesn't seem to work. Any Help ????

Comment: @Shahbaz I don't understand. Please edit your question with the attempted code.

Comment: I have edited this is dummy code not the actual one but this is what I am doing actually

Comment: @Shahbaz What is `parameterArray` in your example? It should simply be a `new Class<?>[] {Request.class}`.

Comment: I got the issue now actually lClass.getMethod( "execRequest", parameterArray) was happening from our framework where parameterArray array was consisting of the DelRequest.class. I added a condition check and made it Request.class and it is working